# LARAVEL ATTACH OR SYNC NOT WORKING FINE ON SERVER SIDE

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys

When im trying to sync or attach in server side isn't working, here my models:

Migration Cuenta:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('cuentas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

        $table->id();
        $table->string('accountName');
        $table->integer('potencialP');
        $table->integer('potencialR');
        $table->timestamps();

    });
}
```

Cuenta Model:

```
class Cuenta extends Model
{
use HasFactory;
protected $fillable = ['id','accountName','potencialP','potencialR'];

public function options(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Option','cuentas_options');
}
}
```

Migration Option:

```
 public function up() {
        Schema::create('options', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        
        $table->id();
        $table->string('titulo');
        $table->integer('puntos');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('field_id');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('field_id')->references('id')->on('fields');
    });
}
```

Option Model:

```
class Option extends Model
{
use HasFactory;

protected $fillable = ['id'];

public function cuentas(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Cuenta','cuentas_options');
}
}
```

Cuentas_option MIGRATION:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('cuentas_options', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        
        $table->id();
        $table->string('cuenta_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('option_id');
        // $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('cuenta_id')->references('id')->on('cuentas');
        $table->foreign('option_id')->references('id')->on('options');
    });
}
```

MyExampleCode:

```
$cuenta = Cuenta::find('8963596291');
$option = Option::all()->pluck('id');
$cuenta->options()->sync($option);
return $cuenta;
```

It returns:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`potencial_pr`.`cuentas_options`, CONSTRAINT `cuentas_options_cuenta_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`cuenta_id`) REFERENCES `cuentas` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `cuentas_options` (`cuenta_id`, `option_id`) values (8963596291, 1))
```

In my local server is working properly but not in server hosting, can someone help me?

EDIT:
IM USING LARAVEL 8, AND UPDATED THE CUENTAS_OPTIONS MIGRATIONS:

```
public function up()
    {
    Schema::create('cuentas_options', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('cuenta_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('option_id');
        // $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('cuenta_id')->references('id')->on('cuentas');
        $table->foreign('option_id')->references('id')->on('options');
    });
}
```

THE PROBLEM CONTINUE,
IM USING 10.4.11-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution on local host and 5.6.49-cll-lve - MySQL Community Server (GPL) on server, could be this the problem?

Comment: Have you checked if the MySQL version on your server is the same as your local?

Comment: Add your laravel version as a reference when asking something related, it can help people to identify the problem faster

Comment: Im using laravel 8, 10.4.11-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution on local host and 5.6.49-cll-lve - MySQL Community Server (GPL) on server, could be this the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding the KEYTYPE on the CUENTAS model and AUTO_INCREMENT=FALSE

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be at `$table->string('cuenta_id');` since on `cuentas` table you created the column as an ID, depending on your laravel version it might be an `unsigned integer` or an `unsigned big integer`

To the foreign keys works properly, you have to be sure that the columns related are exacly the same types, with the same charset and everything, in your case, on cuentas table you created it as an integer, an later o created the foreing key as an string

See **Conditions and Restrictions** for foreign keys here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Probably locally you're working with SQLITE that doesn't validate foreing keys in almost every case, try to create an mysql enviroment locally to work with the same aspects

Comment: i updated the migration cuentas_options; but this didn't work :(, my migration code now: public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cuentas_options', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('cuenta_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('option_id');
            // $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('cuenta_id')->references('id')->on('cuentas');
            $table->foreign('option_id')->references('id')->on('options');
        });
    }

Comment: @NicoSocorro the error is the same? Did you rollback and migrate again?

Comment: probably is the database engine, in my example code on server i have to use $cuenta = Cuenta::find('8963596291'); if i use $cuenta = Cuenta::find(8963596291); without quotes, it retrieve null, i have to set up the keytype on the model?